# Unable to install Plesk 11 under Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ubuntu, vps

I just bought an VPS with Ubuntu 13.10 and I want to install Plesk 11, but it seems it refuses to install.

The command:

```
wget -O - http://autoinstall.plesk.com/one-click-installer | sh
```

throws this error:

```
ERROR: Unable to fetch Parallels Installer
```

seriously... what am I doing wrong? Maybe Ubuntu 13.10 is not supported? Is it possible to install using some Ubuntu 12.04 repo or installer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 13.10 is not supported in Plesk 11 now: http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.1/release-notes/parallels-plesk-panel-11.1-for-linux-based-os.html#3

No, you can't just use repos from 12.04 because there is no Parallels installer binary for Ubuntu 13.10.
But even if installer from 12.04 will work on 13.10, it will detect OS version and says that it not supported. :)